# How to set local environment in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, local, environment, detect

I just want to set the local environment into Laravel 4.

In `bootstrap/start.php` I have:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => ['laravel.dev', ''],
));
```

I tried change local to development index in array, but nothing works.
I tried some tips of this page: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration... nothing.

I'm using artisan in console, that always say me:

```
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

Do you really wish to run this command?
```

What I might do to teach Lara that I'm on local environment?

Answer (score 43):

You may try this (In `bootstrap/start.php` file):

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => ['*.dev', gethostname()],
    'production' => ['*.com', '*.net', '*.org']
));
```

Also this is possible:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {

    return gethostname() == 'your local machine name' ? 'local' : 'production';
});
```

Comment: local works for me, Haven't tried the production yet. btw Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @The Alpha's great answer - here's a slight modification using array to check for local machines (when you work from more than one location):

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {

    return in_array(
            gethostname(), 
            [
                'first local machine name', 
                'second local machine name'
            ]
        ) ? 
        'local' : 
        'production';

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {

    $substr = substr(gethostname(), "-4");
    return ($substr == ".com" || $substr == ".net" || $substr == ".org") ? 'production' : 'local';

});
```